# How can I create a Composable item on Click?

Tags: kotlin, onclick, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a personal project of designing an app to track the animals on a Goat farm. I have created Cards with the Goat information that the user can enter and put them on a List.

Now I'm looking for a way for the user to create another Card like the ones already implemented when they click a button. How could I do that since calling a Composable from an OnClick doesn't work?

Here's the code, I want the "+" Button in GoatApp to Create another Card.
(FORGIVE THE ROUGH UI, I'M FOCUSING ON THE LOGIC BEHIND IT FIRST)

```
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.scrollable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SolidColor
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.Key.Companion.G
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.googlefonts.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.googlefonts.GoogleFont
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter
import com.example.goats.ui.theme.CustomDialog
import com.example.goats.ui.theme.DataSource.goats
import com.example.goats.ui.theme.Goats
import com.example.goats.ui.theme.GoatsTheme
import com.example.goats.ui.theme.MainViewModel



class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    //private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            GoatsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    GoatsApp()

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GoatsApp() {

    val provider = GoogleFont.Provider(
        providerAuthority = "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
        providerPackage = "com.google.android.gms",
        certificates = R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs

    )
    val fontName = GoogleFont("Lato")

    val fontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(googleFont = fontName, fontProvider = provider)
    )
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(16.dp)
    .fillMaxHeight(0.90f)) {

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))){
        Button(onClick = {  }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp), modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))  {
            Text(text = "+")
        }
    Text(text = "Does",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp),
       fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
       textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
       fontFamily = fontFamily,
       fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
    )


    }
Row{
    GoatList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
}

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(0.95f)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(13.dp))){
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp), modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray))  {
            Text(text = "+")
        }
        Text(text = "Bucks",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(12.dp),
            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraLight
        )
    }

    GoatList(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))

}
}



@Composable
fun GoatCard(allGoats: Goats, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
//val years = allGoats.age.toString()



    var stateName by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var stateAge by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val imageUri = rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }
    val myImage = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        imageUri.value.ifEmpty { R.drawable.pexels_anna_shvets_5953826}

    )
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
            uri: Uri? -> uri?.let {imageUri.value = it.toString()}
    }

Card(modifier = Modifier) {
    Row{

     Image(painter = myImage, contentDescription = (stateName),
         modifier = Modifier.size(68.dp),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)

Column(Modifier.width(120.dp)) {

        Text(text = stateName, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall)
    Row{
        Text(text = stringResource(allGoats.breed), modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)
        Text(stateAge, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)

       Box {
        Button(onClick = { viewModel.isGoatClick() },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.LightGray)) { }
            Text(text = "More",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(end = 6.dp, top = 12.dp))





       }
    }

    if(viewModel.isDialogShown) {
        CustomDialog(onDismiss = {viewModel.onDismissDialog()},
            myGoats = Goats(
                name = allGoats.name,
                age = allGoats.age,
                breed = allGoats.breed),
            onValueChange = { stateName = it },
            value = stateName,
            onAgeValueChange = {stateAge = it},
            ageValue = stateAge,
            launcher = launcher,
            myImage = myImage

            )
    }


}
    }
}
}



@Composable
fun GoatList(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(1), modifier.padding(8.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(goats) { allGoats ->
            GoatCard(allGoats = allGoats, viewModel = MainViewModel())
        }

    }

}


@Composable
@Preview
fun previewApp() {
GoatsApp()
}
```

EDIT::

Here is what the DataSource file looks like (that's the file that holds the list)

```
object DataSource {
    val goats =
        mutableListOf(
            Goats(R.string.red, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.little_goat, R.string.alpine, 8),
            Goats(R.string.nana, R.string.alpine, 7),
            Goats(R.string.sharkie, R.string.alpine, 10)

        )


}
```

I used an if function with isButtonClicked boolean to add an item to the list, that works, but for only one item. I need each button click to add another item

```
if (isButtonClicked) {

          goats.add(Goats(R.string.red, R.string.alpine, 7))
}
```

Comment: the best and easiest approach is when user clicks on button try adding a dialog for him to fill in informations then when he clicks on Done as that Goat to the Goats list. how to do that? will when add is clicked have it change a Boolean to true and use this Boolean in If condition that has Dialog inside it, look online you will find a lot of these examples

Comment: Somewhere you have a list of goats you’re using in the GoatList Composable, right? Just add the new goat to that list. It needs to be a mutable state list.

Comment: Yes, my list is in an object, so I can't use it as a mutableStateList

Comment: I edited the question to add the code for the List file, I'm not sure how I could use mutableStateList with the Data Source object